# How to access a hash by key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to build a Rails helper that will create a nested dropdown menu containing links where the top most is either "All" or the current param and the dropdown contains the other options excluding the current param if there is one.

For example, if I have no `post_type` param I would see:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">All</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Discussions</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Snaps</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Code</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Links</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But if I had a `post_type` param of 'discussion' then I would see:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Discussions</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Snaps</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Code</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Links</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In my view I have:

```
<ul class="filter-menu">
  <li>
    <%= current_post_type(params) %>
    <ul class="filter-menu__drop-down">
      <%= list_post_types(params) %>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In my Helper I have:

```
module PostsHelper

  def post_types
    @post_types = {
        :all => {
            :text => 'All post types',
            :icon => 'icon-file-text2',
            :post_type => nil}
    }, {
        :discussions => {
            :text => 'Discussions',
            :icon => 'icon-bubbles2',
            :post_type => 'discussions'}
    }, {
        :snaps => {
            :text => 'Snaps',
            :icon => 'icon-images',
            :post_type => 'snaps'}
    }, {
        :code => {
            :text => 'Code',
            :icon => 'icon-embed2',
            :post_type => 'code'}
    }, {
        :links => {
            :text => 'Links',
            :icon => 'icon-link',
            :post_type => 'links'}
    }
  end

  def post_type_text(icon, text, drop_down = false)
    raw('<i class="' + icon + '"></i> ' + text + (drop_down ? ' <span class="chevron">&#9662;</span>' : ''))
  end

  def post_type_path(post_type)
    posts_path(:filter => params[:filter], :time => params[:time], :post_type => post_type)
  end

  def current_post_type(params)
    if params[:post_type].present? # todo: check matches above
      post_type = params[:post_type].downcase
      link_to post_type_text(post_types[post_type][:icon], post_types[post_type][:text], true), post_type_path(post_types[post_type][:post_type])
    else
      link_to post_type_text(post_types[:all][:icon], post_types[:all][:text], true), post_type_path(post_types[:all][:post_type])
    end
  end

  def list_post_types(params)
    post_types.each do |post_type| # todo: exclude current post_type
      link_to post_type_text(post_types[post_type][:icon], post_types[post_type][:text]), post_type_path(post_types[post_type][:post_type])
    end
  end

end
```

How do I access the hash though? I get an error

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

when doing `post_types[:all]`.

I think it's because `post_types` is returning an array of hashes where as what I want is a hash of hashes accessible by key names.

I could access the `:all` via `post_types[0][:all][:icon]` but this won't work for my other hashes, as I want to access them via `post_types[post_type][:icon]` where `post_type` is the name of the `post_type` key I am trying to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, declare a hash instead of an array:

```
@post_types ||= {
        :all => {
            :text => 'All post types',
            :icon => 'icon-file-text2',
            :post_type => nil},
        :discussions => {
            :text => 'Discussions',
            :icon => 'icon-bubbles2',
            :post_type => 'discussions'},
        :snaps => {
            :text => 'Snaps',
            :icon => 'icon-images',
            :post_type => 'snaps'},
        :code => {
            :text => 'Code',
            :icon => 'icon-embed2',
            :post_type => 'code'},
        :links => {
            :text => 'Links',
            :icon => 'icon-link',
            :post_type => 'links'}
    }
```

---

The problem is here:

```
post_types.each do |post_type| # todo: exclude current post_type
  link_to post_type_text(post_types[post_type] ...
```

You are already iterating over your hash, `post_type` here is an array, holding both `key` and `value`.

Use:

```
post_types.each do |k, v| # todo: exclude current post_type
  link_to post_type_text(v[:icon] ...
```

To understand what’s going on:

```
post_types.each do |post_type| # todo: exclude current post_type
  puts post_type.inspect
```

Also, sidenote: instantiate the instance variable only once:

```
def post_types
  #           ⇓⇓⇓ HERE
  @post_types ||= {...}
```

Comment: How would I access one directly using a param? e.g. `params[:post_type]` and then access that in the array of hashes?

Comment: I do not understand this question. Use `puts post_type.inspect` or `binding.pry` directly inside `post_type.each` and you’ll get all you need.

Comment: Well I need to get a hash from that list by it's key name. So if the `params[:post_type]` was to be `discussions` then I would want to access the hash `:discussion` and access it's values, so I can create that link.

Comment: Also doing `v[:icon]` is giving me this error `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Your question is how to access an item in the hash, right? The answer is `hash[item]`, or `hash.fetch(item, nil)`.

Comment: I've solved it with: `post_type = params[:post_type].downcase.to_sym`

Answer (score 0):

This what I have ended up with in the end to solve my problem.

Massive thanks to **mudasobwa** whose answer I have accepted but I wanted to share what the final code looked like for anyone who comes across this.

```
module PostsHelper

  def post_types
    @post_types ||= {
        :all => {
            :text => 'All post types',
            :icon => 'icon-file-text2',
            :post_type => nil},
        :discussions => {
            :text => 'Discussions',
            :icon => 'icon-bubbles2',
            :post_type => 'discussions'},
        :snaps => {
            :text => 'Snaps',
            :icon => 'icon-images',
            :post_type => 'snaps'},
        :code => {
            :text => 'Code',
            :icon => 'icon-embed2',
            :post_type => 'code'},
        :links => {
            :text => 'Links',
            :icon => 'icon-link',
            :post_type => 'links'}
    }
  end

  def post_type_text(icon, text, drop_down = false)
    raw('<i class="' + icon + '"></i> ' + text + (drop_down ? ' <span class="chevron">&#9662;</span>' : ''))
  end

  def post_type_path(post_type)
    posts_path(:filter => params[:filter], :time => params[:time], :post_type => post_type)
  end

  def current_post_type(params)
    post_type = params[:post_type].present? ? params[:post_type].downcase.to_sym : :all
    if post_types.key?(post_type)
      link_to post_type_text(post_types[post_type][:icon], post_types[post_type][:text], true), post_type_path(post_types[post_type][:post_type])
    else
      link_to post_type_text(post_types[:all][:icon], post_types[:all][:text], true), post_type_path(post_types[:all][:post_type])
    end
  end

  def list_post_types(params)
    html = ''
    post_type = params[:post_type].present? ? params[:post_type].downcase.to_sym : :all
    exclude_all = post_types.key?(post_type) ? false : true
    post_types.each do |k, v|
      if exclude_all && k == :all
      else
        html += "<li>#{link_to post_type_text(v[:icon], v[:text]), post_type_path(v[:post_type])}</li>" if k != post_type
      end
    end
    html.html_safe
  end

end
```

Comment: Is this intended to be the accepted answer? If not, please don't create an answer showing your finished code. It confuses people and breaks the format that SO uses. If it is to be the selected answer then SO will allow you to select it after a timeout period.